# Where does a Quick-Time powered application store changes to the user interface?

Tags: user-interface, quicktime, default-settings

I have downloaded an application written with the Quick Time library (for Windows 7).
The application does not need an installation: just unzip it in a directory and run the program.

It works, but I have a problem: the program allows the user to change a lot of values using its interface but does not have an option to reset them to their default values.

What is more problematic is that when I exit the program and run it again, the interface still has the changed values. In the program directory there is no file that stores the changes done to the UI of the program.

I suspect that Quick Time records these changes somewhere, but I can't find the right file.
I have even deleted the application and re-unzipped it to another location - but the UI values still remain the same values changed by me!